# What is the usage of sorted=False in torch.topk?

Tags: pytorch

I am looking at the doc and some discussions about `torch.topk`. It said that there is no guarantee about the returned order if `sorted=False`. So I wonder what is the usage of `sorted=False`? Why does it have this arg? What is the rule of the returned order if we set `sorted=False`?

I have the following example:

```
>>> x = torch.rand(8)
>>> x
tensor([0.8618, 0.0271, 0.5122, 0.2415, 0.4987, 0.4552, 0.2030, 0.7258])
>>> y = torch.topk(x, 3, sorted=False)
>>> y
torch.return_types.topk(
values=tensor([0.7258, 0.8618, 0.5122]),
indices=tensor([7, 0, 2]))
>>> y = torch.topk(x, 3)
>>> y
torch.return_types.topk(
values=tensor([0.8618, 0.7258, 0.5122]),
indices=tensor([0, 7, 2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I could read from the [PyTorch source code](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/239ee7617726f44a11e26515e9545e0ba9d0bbe4/aten/src/ATen/native/TopKImpl.h#L52-L88), when `k` is **small enough** (`k * 64 <= n`), the C++ implementation would run `std::partial_sort` whether or not `sorted` is required, so the result will always be sorted.

**Otherwise**, as is the case in your example (`k * 64` = 192 `> n` = 8), the implementation would first run [`std::nth_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) that "typically" uses the Introselect algorithm ([gcc implementation based on heap?](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/af0c625f6085567522cf55b2ced05f07ec7be67a/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_algo.h#L1913)), and, if `sorted=True`, run an extra `std::sort` on top-`k` positions.

In conclusion,

- The usage of `sorted=False` is when you are interested in only the top-`k` values instead of their order.
- With this arg, you can save a `std::sort` (if `k * 64 > n`) so it's more efficient.
- AFAIK, the returned order with `sorted=False` should be unpredictable, depending on the underlying `std::nth_element` algorithm.